Is there a mathematical language in which you can express that every natural number is reachable from $0$?
In undergraduate texts concerning the foundations of maths I found that the natural numbers can be defined by intersecting every inductive set (a set $A$ which satisfies $\emptyset \in A$ and $x \in A \Rightarrow x \cup \{x\} \in A$). Intuitively I know that set is of the form
$$\{0,0+1,(0+1)+1,((0+1)+1)+1,\dotsc\}$$
where $0$ is the empty set and $+ 1$ represents the function $x \mapsto x \cup \{x\}$. But it seems like this intuition/recursion can't be expressed in the meta language used in maths.
More precisely, I want to express reachability in a meta language (not a formal language since they are object languages) though recursion (recursion meant in an informal sense), meaning that for every object in this intersection of all inductive sets I can reach it in a finite time starting at $0$ and only using $+1$.
Is there something you are aware of that could help me out?

I think you are confused about the meaning of the terms "metalanguage", "object language" and "formal language". It would be better if you identified a specific text that is of concern to you.

"Reachable" is a vague term. But certainly, if $n$ is reachable, $n+1$ is reachable, so by induction../

"In order
to emphasize the difference in the present context, the formal language L^S
is called the object language (since it is the object of the investigations); the
language English (the language in which the investigations are carried out)
is called the metalanguage. In another context, for example in linguistic
investigations, everyday English could be an object language. Similarly,
first-order languages can play the role of metalanguages in certain settheoretical investigations (cf. VIIA.3). "  - Ebbinghaus, mathematical logic. Im refering to their definitions @RobArthan

Not sure what you mean , but it looks like you want a mathematical /formal statement because you allready have it in english/meta language (for what that is worth, "for every object in this intersection of all inductive sets I can reach it in a finite time starting at 0
and only using +1" is that you are looking for? Maybe
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms helps

Yes, this is exactly it. My mind automatically infers these kinds of rules about reachability from 0. As I understand it, mathematics is generally independent of formal languages like the first order logic. But I think that this independence allows for vagueness and perhaps uncertainty. @ThomasAndrews

Second-Order Logic: Ancestral relation.

I feel like Gottlob Frege would be a little depressed reading this question, as you've seemingly thrown to the side a very natural way to express reachability -- namely that being reachable in a finite number of steps from $0$ just means being in the smallest inductive set containing $0$.

The quote from Ebbinghaus does not preclude the possibility that metalanguages are formal. You should read Tarski's original paper on this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth.

the "+1" is called the successor operation, maybe using that search term could help you a bit

@MauroALLEGRANZA I've looked into it a bit and I think your reasoning is that you define a successor relationsship aSb :$\Leftrightarrow$ b = a $\cup$ { a }, and form the ancestral relation S* which is the smallest transitive set/class containing S. The natural numbers are then { x | 0 S* x or 0 =x }. This approach certainly offers new insight but S*, by definition, might not be closable in countably (informal meaning) many steps; take for an example the smallest σ-algebra containing a set A, it is not possible to close  (fusing complement and union into one operator) A in countably many steps

What is "reachable?"

??? See Frege's Theorem: "Frege’s definition of the concept natural number can now be stated in terms of the weak-ancestral of Predecessor: x is a natural number if and only if x is a member of the predecessor-series beginning with 0". The full machinery needs SOL (and all the details are in the SEP's linked article). Yes, basically it is the set-theoretical construction rewritten in "pure" logic.

Accessibility in the sense I think you mean, can be defined in the language of a ZFC-like set theory.
Example: It can be shown that for not just the natural numbers, but any set $X$, element $x_0\in X$ and successor function $f: X\to X$, induction holds on structure $(X,f,x_0)$ if and only if accessibility holds on $(X,f,x_0)$.
Formally, we have:
$\text{Induction}(x,f,x_0) \iff \text{Accessible}(x,f,x0)$
Where, for any set $X$, $~x_0\in X$ and function $f: X\to X$, we can define:
$\text{Induction}(X,f, x_0) \iff \forall P:[P\subset X ~\land~ x_0 \in P$ $~~~~~~\land~ \forall x\in P:f(x)\in P \implies P=X]$
As requested...
$\text{Accessible}(X,f,x_0) \iff \forall P: [P\subset X ~\land~ \exists x\in P ~\land~ x_0\notin P$
$~~~~\implies \exists x:[x\in X ~\land~ [x\notin P ~\land~ f(x) \in P]]]$
The negation of Accessible is given by:
$\neg \text{Accessible}(X,f,x_0) \iff \exists P: [P\subset X ~\land~ \exists x\in P ~\land~ x_0\notin P$
$~~~~\land \forall x:[x\in X \implies [f(x) \in P \implies x\in P]]]$
Informally, if some region of $X$ is not accessible starting from point $x_0$, then it is impossible to cross that region's boundary via the path given by the successor function $f$. That region is in some sense "isolated" from the rest of $X$.
To apply my theorem to the set of natural numbers, you would have: $X=N, x_0=0, f(x)=S(x),$ with $S$ being the usual successor function on $N$. Obviously induction holds on $(N,S,0).$ Then so must accessibility as defined here.

Your comment definitively offers further insight. The intended argument, I suppose, is that you can throw everything that is not on the natural number line into a set, and by definition of not being on the number line, they won't be accessible. But the problem is whether you can form the set of every number not on the number line or, equivalently, to form the set only containing the natural number line. Being on the natural number line would mean something like there exists a representation of n = ((...((0+1)+1)...)+1)+1

@light That was not my intention. Note that induction can hold even on finite sets. Example: $X = {0,~1},~ x_0=0,~ f(0)=1, ~f(1)=0$. Accessibility will also hold in this case. Induction will not hold if $f(0)=f(1)=0.$ Then $1$ will not be accessible from $0$ under $f$.

@light To apply my theorem to the set of natural numbers, you would have: $X=N, ~x_0=0, ~f(x)=S(x),$ with $S$ being the usual successor function on $N$.

I can see how this is the closest formulation of accessibility in set theory. But I think a justification is missing why or how it is equivalent to the casual meaning of accessible, but I think one needs to presuppose a theory of counting.

I find the negation of accessible (above) is more intuitive. Informally, $(X,f,x_0)$ is not accessible if some subset $P \subset X$ is "isolated" from the rest of $X.$ This does not rely on counting. $P$ is non-empty and excludes $x_0$.

"Isolated" in the sense that no element of $x\in P$  has a pre-image under $f$ that is not in $P$.
